# RavenDB connections over HTTPS

Tags: ravendb

We are setting up replication between RavenDB instances running in server mode. The instances are in different availability zones so we need a secure connection between the servers. According this [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/T4EVvoWpuKk) SSL is not supported in server mode but

> should be easy to add

Is there an extensibility point in the API where SSL support can be plugged in?

Comment: Did you try it? If so, can you share the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doesn't have any place for this currently, but I'm sure it would be a welcome contribution if you were so inclined to write this and submit a pull request.  The underlying server is just a `System.Net.HttpListener`, which can be wired for ssl.

Your entry point would be at [Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.StartListening()](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Server/HttpServer.cs#L318)

You would want the SSL certificate to be as easy to configure as the hostname or port.  The cert itself should probably be pulled in from the Windows certificate store.